# World Map in unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

*To make it simple: I would like to have a real world map with a proper scale in Unity.*

**Goal:**

My goal is to have a **map** like in **Heart of Iron IV**. But I want to make it **really precise** with a **scale** for **calculating travel time** for units. I also want to **apply a zoom** *(and if it's possible, when I zoom to a certain value change the map to a detailed map with roads, etc...)*.

*Heart of Iron IV map:*

[image: Heart of Iron IV map:]

**What i planned to do:**

I planned to **take a map on internet**, put it in **Photoshop** and make some **separate parts of every country**. But I don't know if it's the best way around. Because i also planned to make some smaller maps, like a single country.

**What I tried so far:**

I tried Using google map API, but I don't think it's the right tool for a unity game.
I searched for softwares that can create precise maps.
I went trough forums to check how smart people would go about this.

But I still don't know what to choose...

**Conclusion:**

I want a precise world map. I want to be able to make a zoom system able to change the details on the map. I want a scale on it, like 1km = 1 Unity unit *(i don't remember what unity metrics are for 2D)*.

**So what would be the best way around this ?**

Thanks for your time (and sorry for my english).

Comment: You can have some hidden maps that appear and replace the originals when you start to get close.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Yeah for the zoom that's what i'm thinking. So the plan would be to create multiple gameObject, each with more details. But this would break my scale no ?

Comment: I dont think it would break the scale but you could do it in a shader so you wouldnt need multiple game objects.

Comment: I never used shaders before, I think this little project will be more complex than I planned it to be... x) But I will try your idea that can be a nice way to learn ! Thank you :)